# Heroku/Git Push Dependancy Error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to Git push my Django website up to Heroku. When it comes to this dependancy, I get this error:

```
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/83/89b5adbc37d1bbf7b486a2c1c00e8037e6f801e8c053c4897bb82d9510c6/PyAutoGUI-0.9.36.tar.gz (46kB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-pfkxr3gz/PyAutoGUI/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
remote:                version=__import__('pyautogui').__version__,
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-pfkxr3gz/PyAutoGUI/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
remote:                from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-pfkxr3gz/PyAutoGUI/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 7, in <module>
remote:                from Xlib.display import Display
remote:            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Xlib'
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-pfkxr3gz/PyAutoGUI/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to aaronmaziewebsite.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/aaronmaziewebsite.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/aaronmaziewebsite.git'
```

I already have PyAutoGUI and Xlib installed on my machine.

I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DggiEkbCTg

https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/go-live-with-django-project-and-heroku/

Any advice?

Comment: Why do you have GUI libraries in your requirements.txt? I'm sure that's not what the tutorial tells you to do.

Comment: I did "pip freeze > requirements.txt" as the tutorial says and then committed the updated file. What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: You should be developing your project in a virtualenv so that it does not include other irrelevant libraries you might have previously installed. If that tutorial doesn't mention that, it's not a good one. Clearly GUI libraries are not needed for a web site. At the very least, remove PyAutoGUI from the requirements, but really that file should only include the things you installed for this project: django, psycopg2, dj-database-url and gunicorn.

Comment: Would recommend using a pipfile in a pipenv...it is easy to intall packages to that particular environment and that wi automatically update your pipfile.lock which will be recognized by Heroku that it has changed among pushing.

Comment: @OhGreatOne could you elaborate further on how to do this? I have pipenv. Is there a command I should run to replace the requirement.txt?

Comment: https://docs.pipenv.org/basics/  this also has a way to automatically turn your reqs.txt into a pipfile. It is pretty cool.

Comment: After deleting the requirements.txt, I ran "pipenv install" and then ran the git push master and came to the same error (I didn't run the pipenv shell). I guess it included all of my pip packages again. Then I made another requirements.txt and deleted all the unnecessary packages and even though I deleted both PyAutoGUI and Xlib, it still gave the same error..

Comment: I made a git commit with the requirements.txt and I'm pretty sure that is the problem

Comment: Alright, I figured that out. Thank you guys!